# How to dump sql in docker for symfony doctrine

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, docker, dump

I moved to docker for my development environment. I am using symfony 2.8.49,mysql in docker.

Before I move to docker, I was able to see only necessary dump with this code. It wasn't dumping the whole database sql queries. It was just dumping the new entities or features like new columns. (which is not existing table or columns or foreign key.)

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql
```

Today when I use this same command in symfony docker, it dumps everything even it is existing table or columns or foreign key.

It is too messy and I need a clear result in docker without using grep.

parameters.yml

```
parameters:
database.host: mysql
database.port: 3306
database.name: *name
database.user: *user
database.password: password
```

docker-compose.yml

```
mysql:
build: ./docker/mysql
volumes:
  - /var/lib/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
networks:
  main:
    aliases:
      - mysql
```

docker-compose.override.yml

```
symfony:
 build:
  context: ./docker/symfony-alpine
  dockerfile: Dockerfile
 extra_hosts:
  - "my.local:0.0.0.0"
 ports:
  - "8080:80"
 environment:
  - ENABLE_XDEBUG=1
  - XDEBUG_CONFIG=remote_host=192.168.0.109
  - PHP_IDE_CONFIG=serverName=symfony
mysql:
 ports:
  - "3307:3306"
```

Comment: Then you should consult with the docker maintainer. It's not PHP Problem anyway.

Comment: The problem might be related with the database that is being used. Could you please echo the envvar `DATABASE_URL` that is used to connect to the database? You can do so by typing `echo $DATABASE_URL` into your terminal. If that does not return anything, check for the value in your env-files, starting with `.env.local` then `.env.dev` or `.env` depending on whether they exist.

Comment: You could try generating a migration using doctring:migrations:diff and having a look at the SQL that is generated in there.

Comment: @dbruman I don't have DATABASE_URL in my env file. just I have a mysql volume defination in my docker-compose.yml file. which is : /var/lib/mysql:/var/lib/mysql

Comment: If you don't have the `DATABASE_URL` in your env file, then maybe it's stored as environment variable. When you go into your php-docker container and run the `echo $DATABASE_URL` what do you get? If you don't get anything back, then that might be the issue. Running the command requires the database connection. Could you post your `docker-compose.yml` this will help with explaining how to pass the database url into your php container to make the command use the right connection.

Comment: @dbrumann
Is the .env (dotenv) not introduced into Symfony 4? When he uses Symfony 2.8 he dont have any .env file in my point of view...

Comment: You are right, sorry. I missed that part and since it was a docker environment I just assumed it's a 4.x project. In that case, could you check your `parameters.yml` for the database settings and whether they match the ones from your docker-compose setup?

Comment: @Stormnorm this command does not work in my symfony version 2.8.49.

Comment: @dbrumann I have added the related part of parameters.yml and docker-compose.yml to the post

Comment: The settings look fine. Are you calling the command from inside your container, i.e. are you running `docker-compose exec symfony bash` and then the bin/console command?

Comment: Do you have access to the local folder `/var/lib/mysql` the volume is mounted to? Maybe it's an issue due to file permissions?

Comment: @dbrumann yes I run the command in the symfony container, I don't use docker-compose I use like this : docker exec -it symfony_1 bash and I go to inside of my project

Comment: @dbrumann what permmission I need to give? Yes, I can't do cd to the mysql directory and also my database named directory in /var/lib/mysql. I changed the permissons to 600 it didn't work, after I changed to 777 it still same.

Comment: Try mounting it to a local folder inside your project, e.g. if you have a docker subdirectory, what I usually do is something like `./docker/mysql/data:/var/lib/mysql` and then put the data folder in my `.gitignore`. At least on Windows Docker is only allowed to access certain directory, like your home folder and I assume it's similar on Linx/Mac, but have never looked into it more.